# How to detect whether the a 2-position fan connector on a PCB is plugged or not without turning on the fan?

Tags: motor, connector, motor-controller, detection

On the PCB just a simple circuit to drive a 2-wire fan when we plug it to a 2-position connector on the PCB.

Is there a way to modify something on the circuit to know if the fan (DC motor) is plugged in or not without turning on the fan (to detect its current consumption etc.).

Comment: Are you allowed to pass a small current through the fan to detect if it's there?

Comment: Is there a load switch on the PCB to turn the fan on and off?

Comment: how you will pass a small current to the fan ? @Simon-B

Comment: No @Jens there is no load switch

Comment: I was thinking of a reasonably large resistor (perhaps a few tens of kilohms) in series with the fan.  Then read the voltage using a GPIO pin on a microcontroller.  But if there is no load switch on the board, how do you intend to plug the fan in without turning it on?

Comment: I will send a signal to the driver to enable the fan so it is not a physical load switch but if we added a series resistor as you said when we plug the fan the resistor will be load so we detect if there is load or not right ? @SimonB

Comment: Is the connector such that an infrared slot sensor could be fitted around it? OK, so anything else blocking the slot would be sensed, but it *might* be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 3-circuit connector: 2 circuits for the fan and a circuit to sense its presence.

Connect the two wires to the fan to two circuits of the plug. Also connect a shorting jumper between the ground wire of the fan wires and the third contact on the plug.

On the PCB side, connect the two fan wires to the switched supply. Also connect the third wire to a pull-up resistor to 5 V. Sense the voltage of that line:

- If it's 5 V, the fan is unplugged
- If it's 0 V, the fan is plugged.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a reasonably high resistor (maybe tens or hundreds of kilohms) in *parallel* with whatever is switching the fan on or off.

So if you're using high side switching, the resistor would be between the power supply and the fan positive.  If you're using low side switching, it would be between the fan negative and ground.

Now measure the voltage between that fan terminal and ground.  Because the fan will have a much lower resistance than the resistor, if the fan is connected, the voltage will change.